# Where can I find a list of think tanks broken down by funding source?

Tags: funding, ngo

I'm doing research on funding for think tanks. I'd like to know if anyone maintains a database of who funds think tanks. Ideally, the list would state each organization that has contributed to a think tank within the last few years, but I would be happy with more general data as well (i.e. funded by a government, funded by an individual, funded by a nonprofit, etc).

Comment: How do you define a "think tank"?

Comment: I would define a think tank as an organization that is dedicated to producing public policy analysis. A list of global think tanks can be found here: https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1017&context=think_tanks